# Strange behavior in select drop-down in a Django template

Tags: python, django, forms, boolean

I'm working on two linked form fields (`Class` and `Students`) where the user selects a class from the drop-down menu and then the students form field updates with the corresponding list of students.

I have it all working with the AJAX logic, except...except...I have run into some strange behavior when trying to apply the `selected` attribute to the `<option>` tags.

**views.py**

```
def load_students(request):
    classid = request.GET.get('classid')
    contractid = request.GET.get('contractid')

    # Lookup students for given class
    students = Student.objects.getclass(classid=classid) 

    if(contractid):

         # Generate list of students associated with this contract
        contract_party_list = []
        contract_parties = ContractParty.objects.get_contract_parties(
            contractid=contractid
        )

        for mycontractparty in contract_parties:
            contract_party_list.append(mycontractparty.partyuserid)

        # Generate new student list (with appended contract user info)
        student_list = []

        for mystudent in students:
            # Set flag to determine whether student is part of contract
            if(mystudent.studentuserid in contract_party_list):
                selectedFlag = True
            else:
                selectedFlag = False

            # Add updated student info to new student list
            student_list.append(
                {
                    'studentuserid':mystudent.studentuserid, 
                    'firstname':mystudent.firstname, 
                    'lastname':mystudent.lastname, 
                    'selectedFlag': selectedFlag
                }
            )

        students = student_list

    return render(request, 'dropdown_ajax.html', {'students': students})
```

**dropdown_ajax.html**

```
{% if students %}
{% for student in students %}
    <option 
        value="{{ student.studentuserid }}" 
        {% if student.selectedFlag %} selected="selected"{% endif %}
    >
        {{ student.firstname }} {{ student.lastname }}
    </option>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

This line is causing me problems: `{% if student.selectedFlag %} selected="selected"{% endif %}`

The strange behavior is that the "selected" attribute never gets applied, even though `student.selectedFlag` evaluates to True.

A couple things I tried:

1. I moved the line above outside of the  tag to see what it would do.  It displays the text "selected" for the correct entries.
2. I replaced `if student.selectedFlag` with `if student.studentuserid == 1` and the correct student was selected in the field.
3. I passed "True" / "False and numeric values for `selectedFlag` instead of Boolean.  I tried `if student.selectedFlag == "True"`.  Nothing.

I'm not sure what's causing this behavior.  My guess it's something to do with the Django Boolean variables not being evaluated correctly within the `<option>` fields.

Comment: What is the strange behavior? are you facing all the options being selected even though there are some that were not supposed?

Comment: The strange behavior is that the `selected` attribute is not being applied when I have logic that includes `selectedFlag`, even though the values are being passed fine.  When I reference a different field to determine whether the `<option>` tag should be `selected` (i.e. `studentuserid == 1`), it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual...the solution manifests itself after taking a break :)  It's official...I'm an idiot.  In my testing, I was looking at two different scenarios.  The one that was giving me the "weird behavior", I wasn't passing the `contractid` value.  So it was never getting to the logic that sets the `selected` options.  D'oh!  Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a django issue - it's an issue with the html. The html attribute should be treated as a boolean (present/not present), not given the value "selected". The correctly rendered html should look something like this:

```
<option value="value" selected>...</option>
```

not this, which I think is what's happening in yours:

```
<option value="value" selected="selected">...</option>
```

So the corrected code would looks like this:

**dropdown_ajax.html**

```
{% if students %}
{% for student in students %}
    <option 
        value="{{ student.studentuserid }}" 
        {% if student.selectedFlag %} selected{% endif %}
    >
        {{ student.firstname }} {{ student.lastname }}
    </option>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yeah. I had tried that as well, but no dice.  Thanks, though.  When I hard-code `selected` or `selected="selected"` it works.